# Assign groups with preassigned conditions in R

Tags: r

I have such a matrix(df1):

```
vid   col1     
103   9       
103   3       
103   7    
103   6    
104   7 
104   8  
104   9  
105   6   
105   8 
106   8  
106   9  
106   4   
106   6
```

I have another matrix (df2):

```
vid   col1     
103   0       
104   1       
105   5    
106   3
```

I want to assign groups to df1 so that group IDs are conditional on df2 based on vid.

Namely, I would like the following manipulation on df1, desired output:

```
   vid   col1   col2  
    103   9    0  
    103   3    0   
    103   7    0
    103   6    0
    104   7    1
    104   8    1
    104   9    1
    105   6    5  
    105   8    5
    106   8    3 
    106   9    3
    106   4    3
    106   6    3
```

I was trying the following:

```
df1<-cbind(df1,0)
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df2))
{
    if(df1[i,1]==df2[j,1]){
      df1[i,3]=df2[j,2]
    }
    else{
      df1[i,3]=NA
    }

  }  
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, could anyone help me with this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` to merge the 2 dataframes together

```
merge(df1, df2, by='vid')
```

output would be

```
   vid   col1   col2  
    103   9    0  
    103   3    0   
    103   7    0
    103   6    0
    104   7    1
    104   8    1
    104   9    1
    105   6    5  
    105   8    5
    106   8    3 
    106   9    3
    106   4    3
    106   6    3
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you should make a vector variable, this variable will be the third column of your final data frame.

```
Vec=vector()
```

I am assuming here, you have only 4 ID's which are

```
df2$vid
[1] 103 104 105 106
```

Now fill the third column while traversing all rows of first data frame **df1**.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1))
{
  if(df1[i,1]==103){Vec[i]=df2[df2$vid==103,2]}
  if(df1[i,1]==104){Vec[i]=df2[df2$vid==104,2]}
  if(df1[i,1]==105){Vec[i]=df2[df2$vid==105,2]}
  if(df1[i,1]==106){Vec[i]=df2[df2$vid==106,2]}

}
```

Finally, combine the third column with data frame **df1**.

```
df1=cbind(df1,Vec)
```